# Finding weak solutions

Tags: distribution-theory

I am trying to understand how to solve differential equations of distributions.

For example if one consider

$ u' + u = \delta_{0}$, where $ u \in \mathcal{D}'$,

this would correspond to

$<u, -\phi' + \phi> = <\delta_0, \phi> = \phi(0)$.

How would one in general go on to solve this? And can one see if it is solvable? I just made this up so I don't know if a solution exists.

Would it be possble to use Fourier Transforms?

Comment: look for a function $u$ such that $u'+u=0$ except at $x=0$ and which jumps by $1$ at $x=0$ (its only point of discontinuity). Any solution of the homogeneous equation $u'+u=0$ in $\mathcal D'$ is in fact a smooth function.

Comment: Ok, so then for example $C\theta(x)e^{-x}$ is a distribution which solves the equation? $\theta$ is the Heaviside function.

Comment: yes, with $C=1$ (try to prove it)

Comment: Yes, $<u' + u, \phi> = < ce^{-x}\delta_{0}, \phi > = <\delta, ce^{-x}> = c\phi(0) \implies c = 1$. Can we be certain we have found all solutions?

Comment: up to adding a solution of the homogeneous equation $v'+v=0$. They are just $ce^{-x}$ (i.e. just ordinary solutions, no weird distributions). To see it: it is equivalent to $(e^xv)'=0$, and now you need to use a theorem saying that $f'=0$ implies $f$ is a constant (you can try to prove it directly, or look it up). Seeing your edit: $\theta(x)e^{-x}$ is the only solution in $\mathscr S'$ and yes, you can easily get it with Fourier (you end up using residue theorem in the end)